# Unable to get number of messages in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am fairly new to kafka. I have created a sample producer and consumer in java. Using the producer, I was able to send data to a kafka topic but I am not able to get the number of records in the topic using the following consumer code.

```
    public class ConsumerTests {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            BasicConfigurator.configure();

            String topicName = "MobileData";
            String groupId = "TestGroup";
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            properties.put("group.id", groupId);
            properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
            properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

            KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
            kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));


try {
  while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(100);
    System.out.println("Record count is " + records.count());
  }
} catch (WakeupException e) {
  // ignore for shutdown
} finally {
  consumer.close();
}

}
}
```

I don't get any exception in the console but consumerRecords.count() always returns 0, even if there are messages in the topic. Please let me know, if I am missing something to get the record details.

Answer (score 0):

The `poll(...)` call should normally be in a loop. It's always possible for the initial `poll(...)` to return no data (depending on the timeout) while the partition assignment is in progress. Here's an example:

```
try {
  while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    System.out.println("Record count is " + records.count());
  }
} catch (WakeupException e) {
  // ignore for shutdown
} finally {
  consumer.close();
}
```

For more info see [this relevant article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/):

Comment: Tried this, still the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you are not producing anymore, and want to see already produced records? In that case, add `properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");`

Comment: I still see messages in the topic.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "I still see messages in the topic". Are you producing at the same time the above consumer is running? How do you verify there are messages in the topic? Did you try starting from the earliest offset?

Comment: I mean the topic still has the messages that was sent previously. I verified it using kafka consumer console.

Comment: I see, and adding that additional property to start from earliest didn't make a difference (in addition to the loop)?

Comment: Yup, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you please update the above code to what you have now? Also make sure the `subscribe()` call is not inside the loop.

Comment: There are errors in your code. The consumer object you're using should have the same name everyone (you now have `kafkaConsumer` and `consumer`). Plus, you haven't added the config setting I mentioned above: `properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");` Please make these changes, run the code, and advise what you see in the output.